# Can I get fields from google-form in my web app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-forms, google-forms-api

I created a form, got a link with the form id, and tried to get the form by `google-api` in this [link](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms/get?hl=ru).

But, after I select the account, it gives me the ***404 Error*** with error `"message": "Requested entity was not found"` on the browser.

How can I get the form data from google-form to my web app and send it?

I will use React/Next.js in my app, so, do I have an option to get this data?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/googleworkspace/node-samples/blob/main/forms/snippets/get_form.js - here the example, but when I try google always ask for tokens, is any options get google-form without auth by tokens, just with json for keyfilePath

Comment: {
    "itemId": "1ba6e747",
    "title": "Email",
    "questionItem": {
    "question": {
      "questionId": "6061b248",
        "required": true,
        "textQuestion": {}
    }
  } for example I have here id for input, but in google-form this id id different and start with entry.183278***, so how I can get correct input id from form and send it